# How to distinguish between clicked and non-clicked item in ListView in Android

Tags: android, listview

I have a scenario here.I am developing a housing app in which the Complex owners can post announcements and flat owners can see it.I am using webservice.The complex owner can add a new announcement(which I am saving in my server) and the flat owners can see those announcements(I am binding the announcements headers into a list view through json parsing and on-clicking a header a full message will be displayed).

Now the problem is in case of new announcements.I want to distinguish between the readed and unreaded messages(just like in our mail).So how can I determine which listview item is clicked or which item is not clicked??And also how can I give them different colors(i.e. to mark an item unreaded or not clicked ??)

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Save all announcements in a table locally in sqlite. Add a column to contain the read unread flag.
While populating the list read from the table and load considering the flag.

Comment: That is a nice idea.Will let you know if this work and will mark this answer as correct.